# Why Toast not getting called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toast

I have Toast in both If and Else statement, all the code in If statement were executed with an exception of the Toast. Else statement work without a problem.

The problem are mainly the Toast in the If statement.

I have tried taking the Toast away from If statement and everything work fine, Tried taking finish() out of the If statement and the Toast still won't get called.

```
if (filterCharSet1 in scannedID || filterCharSet2 in scannedID || filterCharSet3 in scannedID || filterCharSet4 in scannedID || filterCharSet5 in scannedID ) {
                    Log.d("checkcheck","contain")
                    finish()
                    Toast.makeText(this@ScannerActivity , "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}else{

                    Log.d("checkcheck","noContain")
                    finish()
                    Toast.makeText(this@ScannerActivity , "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

The Toast in the Else statement work without a problem, but for some reason the Toast in If statement just don't get called.

Comment: call `finish()` after `Toast`

Comment: Tried, not working

Comment: I dont know why there is upvotes?

Comment: @user1241241 can you point out the problem?

Comment: @PratikButaniAndroidDev , your help will be well appreciated

Comment: you are using this code in your service??

Comment: @BlackBlind I don't get what you mean

Comment: It means You are using this code in sevices or activity?  Now getting my point?

Comment: @BlackBlind the code is to check whether the scanned QRCode when converted to string, does it have certain character. Yes it's perform in an activity, as you can see above, else statement run without a problem, the if statement work fine if the Toast isn't there.

Comment: Log statement is working in both condition??

Comment: @BlackBlind other than the Toast in if statement, everything works fine, if there's a substitute for Toast, I'll try LOL

Comment: Bro I know about log and toast. If Some time toast is not work we can use Log because Log always shows  output . and in your code Log is not working then You have logical error in if condition.

Comment: @BlackBlind I got the solution, the answer from AbdulAzeem is the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Call **finish()** after toast and then try **runonuithread**

```
this@ScannerActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using applicationContext instead of activity. Activity, as a context might be no longer available after calling finish()

Comment: Tried, same problem

Comment: The else statement work like a charm, without a problem with my code above

Comment: Are you sure that the actual ```if``` statement is called?

Comment: Yup, because my Log in the If statement get called

Comment: If I take away the Toast, finish() will also get call

Answer (score 0):

If you call finish() you destroy the activity, which makes this@ScannerActivity invalid.

Comment: `D/checkcheck: https://www.qrcode-monkey.com
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x10 in tid 12290 (Thread-10007)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8603', transport: 'socket'`

Answer (score 0):

Your toast isn't showing up because the `finish` keyword destroys the activity. Simply call `finish` after the Toast; Your code should look like this:

```
if (filterCharSet1 in scannedID || filterCharSet2 in scannedID || filterCharSet3 in scannedID || filterCharSet4 in scannedID || filterCharSet5 in scannedID ) {
                Log.d("checkcheck","contain")
                Toast.makeText(this@ScannerActivity , "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish()
}else{

                Log.d("checkcheck","noContain")
                Toast.makeText(this@ScannerActivity , "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish()
}
```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Comment: Same result, the else statement will work, but when if statement is called, it just do nothing

Comment: even if I take away the finish() from the if statement, the Toast won't even get called

Comment: That's strange.. If the `else` is working, `if` should work too (as long as the conditions are actually satisfied).

Comment: I know the condition is satisfied because my Log in if statement get called

Comment: The finish() and Log.d work without a problem without the Toast, but if the Toast is there, it just do nothing

Comment: What is the type of `scannedID`?

Comment: type string, and I filter out  "."   "$"   "#"   "["   "]"

Comment: so if scannedID contain them, if statement will get called